# What Unix command-line program prints holidays?

Tags: calendar

Ages ago, I remember there was a command-line Unix program that 
would print out major holidays in the USA. With command-line 
options, it could print out Islamic, Discordian, and even Canadian 
holidays.

I can't seem to find this program now. The closest I can get is 
emacs' "list-holidays" function. It's possible the program I 
remember just called an emacs function from the command line or 
something.

EDIT: In addition to 'calendar', 'gcal' will do this too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for [calendar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/calendar)?

This will show all the upcoming holidays.

```
$ calendar
Jul 26  Bilbo rescued from Wargs by Eagles
Jul 26  Independence Day in Liberia
Jul 26  National Day in Maldives
```

This shows all US bank holidays upcoming in the next `+1` days.

```
$ calendar -f /usr/share/calendar/calendar.usholiday -W +1
Nov 11  Veterans' Day
```

This package is maintained by the BSD community and can be installed in debian and ubuntu from `bsdmainutils`.

Comment: Yup, that was it. I feel stupid! I had to do "calendar -f /usr/share/calendar/calendar.fictional" to get the Bilbo one, but that was exactly what I was thinking of, thanks.